# Pylint import check when directories are not the same than the import

Tags: python, import, pylint

I've an unusual question, and I don't find the answer because no one is doing like that :p

I want to use PyLint in order to resolve errors before running the script, especially calling methods from other modules and heritage.

Thing is, my python scripts are not organized the same way than the import.
For exemple I have one module in src/project/module/file.py and the import is like that : progName.app.module
It's because the scripts are precompiled (with operations done on it such as Macros replacement)

But because of that, PyLint is unable to find the folder for the right import.

I can't modify the directories hierarchy, so I have to find a way to tell PyLint that it has to find progName.app.module in src/project/module

If someone ever had this issue...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly multiple solutions to this. First, you can try to write a failure import hook, using astroid's API, which might look as this: https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/blob/master/astroid/brain/brain_six.py#L273. After defining it, you can use the same API for loading a plugin, as in: pylint your_project --load-plugins=qualified.name.for.your.plugin.

This might work most of the time, but if it does not, a normal transform could be used (you can take a look at most of the files in that directory, since they are used just for that, for modifying the AST before running the code).

Alternatively, you could try to play with --init-hook="...", in which you can modify the paths before the analysis, but it does not guarantee that your custom locations would be picked by pylint.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into it !